# How to implement Webview into layoutinflator

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I have got the source code for sliding menu and want to implement a webview into this,  However it doesn't seem to work and can't find a clear answer on how to do this.  Here is my code and hopefully it will make sense on what i am trying to achieve:

```
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.R;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class TestingPage extends Fragment {

public TestingPage(){}  //Have removed this code, but still gives same error
private WebView webView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_testpage, container);

 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Webview1);
 webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
 webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
 webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

 return rootView;

}


}
```

Now the problem i have is under findViewById i have an error with the option of: "Create method findViewById(int)

When i create this (via the option given), i then get no error and then this is what i get:

```
private WebView findViewById(int webview1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
   }
 }
```

Now i am not sure what to do from here?  when i run it and test the app i get this:

```
 09-11 13:39:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(31488): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 09-11 13:39:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(31488): java.lang.NullPointerException
 09-11 13:39:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(31488):   at  com.test.testapp.findViewById(TestingPage.java:33)
 09-11 13:39:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(31488):   at com.test.testapp.onCreateView(TestingPage.java:22)
 09-11 13:39:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(31488):   at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699)
 09-11 13:39:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(31488):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
 09-11 13:39:07.649: E/AndroidRuntime(31488):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
 09-11 13:47:58.229: E/AndroidRuntime(32545): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-11 13:47:58.229: E/AndroidRuntime(32545): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first
```

**Edited**

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/Webview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDITED WITH CORRECT CODE**

The problem was at this code:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_campsites, container);
```

How i resolved the issue was adding false at the end:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_campsites, container, false);
```

Everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

replace your code with this code

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_testpage, container);

webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Webview1);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

just change `webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Webview1);` line

Answer (score 0):

you are webview inside the rootview and there id is inside the root view

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_testpage, container);
webView = (WebView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.Webview1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much that took care of the error but now when running the app i get this:

Comment: 09-11 13:47:58.229: E/AndroidRuntime(32545): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 13:47:58.229: E/AndroidRuntime(32545): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: R.layout.fragment_testpage post xml

Comment: I have posted the xml file as well

Comment: Remove this line and post now error public TestingPage(){}

Comment: Have tried as suggested, but is giving same error as stated above:  The specified child already has a parent.  You must call removeView() on the child's parent first"

Comment: 09-11 13:47:58.229: E/AndroidRuntime(32545): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 13:47:58.229: E/AndroidRuntime(32545): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Answer (score 0):

change
`View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_testpage, container);`

to

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_testpage, container,false);
```

absence of "false" parameter in inflate method will result in adding "rootView" to "container".
Which will later cause the exception when returning "rootView" in onCreateView method

Comment: Before you posted your answer.

Comment: i would have up voted your answer but i need 15 points and higher to that, but consider this an up vote!